# listing the keys in a dictionary created from mongoengine object

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I'm working on a little flask project and I've used mongoengine to get the info from a mongodb document as follows:

```
results = User.objects.filter(class_name=class_name)
```

I now want to create a table that will display the data from the results with the keys in the table header and then the data below in rows.  I'm having trouble displaying the keys, for example if I do:

```
for key in results.keys(): 
    print (key)
```

but I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'BaseQuerySet' object has no attribute 'keys'

When I print the results, the terminal shows:

```
[<User: User object>, <User: User object>]
[<User: User object>, <User: User object>]
[<User: User object>, <User: User object>]
```

So, I guess it isn't a normal dictionary or something? I'm just learning using python and coding in general so any help would be appreciated for this home project, thanks

Comment: You can use print(dir(key)) to see what methods you can use on it

Answer (score 1):

As a first step, you could ...

```
print(type(myresults))
```

... so you learn what type of object is returned.

You can also e.g. `print(dir(myresults))`, so you will get a list of attributes and methods of this object.

Comment: Thanks, I've done what you said but they don't make any sense to me.  The object returned is <class 'flask_mongoengine.BaseQuerySet'> and the list of attributes and methods is like a different language: ['_BaseQuerySet__dereference', '__bool__', '__call__', '__class__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', .... and a whole lot more

Comment: additionally, i've read the mongoengine docs but can't see anywhere where it can help https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, in the BaseQueryList there is one method called as_pymongo, it can be used to get rows as list of dict like where we get pymongo:

results = User.objects.filter(class_name=class_name).as_pymongo

so now when I print the results, it prints as a dictionary list:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5f01925804723f383c2dd483'), 'user_id': '2', 'first_name': 'Alan', 'last_name': 'Rice', 'username': 'arice', 'password': 'xxxxxxxx', 'class_name': '6a', 'E6001': '2', 'E6002': '2', 'E6003': '2', 'E6004': '9', 'E6005': '2', 'E6006': '2', 'E6007': '9', 'E6008': '2', 'E6009': '2', 'E6010': '2', 'E7001': '7', 'E7002': '2', 'E7003': '2', 'E7004': '7', 'E7005': '2', 'E7006': '2', 'E7007': '2', 'E7008': '2', 'E7009': '2', 'E7010': '2', 'M6001': '2', 'M6002': '2', 'M6003': '2', 'M6004': '2', 'M6005': '2', 'M6006': '2', 'M6007': '2', 'M6008': '2', 'M6009': '2', 'M6010': '2', 'M7001': '2', 'M7002': '2', 'M7003': '2', 'M7004': '2', 'M7005': '2', 'M7006': '2', 'M7007': '2', 'M7008': '2', 'M7009': '2', 'M7010': '2'}
```